# Google Progressive App (PWA) Can we use IONIC?

Tags: angular, polymer, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I want to build one Google Progressive App (PWA).

Can anyone suggest me that can I use IONIC 3/angular 4 for Google Progressive App?

Or I have to use Polymer?
Thanks

Comment: Read https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/6-myths-of-progressive-web-apps-81e28ca9d2b1 about how is Google related to PWA and what kind of technology PWA might be built from.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily develop `PWA` apps using `Ionic 3 /Angular`. The ionic framework has that feature out of the box. But if you need to develop Google Progressive web Apps then you need to use vanilla javascript. You cannot mix those 2 each other.

You can see how to develop PWA using `Ionic 3 /Angular` using below links.

[**What Progressive Web Apps can do for you**](https://blog.ionicframework.com/what-progressive-web-apps-can-do-for-you/)

[**How to make PWAs with Ionic**](https://blog.ionicframework.com/how-to-make-pwas-with-ionic/)

Answer (score 0):

Ionic comes with base ServiceWorker and Manifest support by default.

Uncomment the following line in index.html:

```
  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->
```

You can subsequently change the caching strategy and implementation within `src/service-worker.js`.